# PHP replacment for date_create and date_timestamp_get

Tags: php, date

im running php on version 5.1.6 and the functions date_create and date_timestamp_get arent there on that php version.

So what replacment Can i do that will work and do the same as :

```
$date = date_create();
$curr_date_time =  date_timestamp_get($date);
```

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = date();
$curr_date_time = strtotime($date);
```

or more simple use:

```
$curr_date_time = time();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php